# Extension in php doesn't work

Tags: php, c

For creating an extension in php 7.0 there is a line used zend_unwrap_reference

```
zend_unwrap_reference(&retval);
```

when i am execution that file it gives an error like that:

> ‘zend_unwrap_reference’ was not declared in this scope

. How can i solve this?

Comment: Which headers are you including? You'd normally pull in `php.h`, which in turn would grab `zend.h` and `zend_operators.h`, which is where this is declared

Comment: in a test.h file in wrote                                                                                                                                                                                    extern "C" {
#include "php.h"
}                                                                                                           in another .h file i included test.h file

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Git repository](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.h), you may have to include `zend_operators.h`.